# Java - Create generic list with class Object as generic parameter?

Tags: java, class, generics, parameters

Suppose I have an object `Class<?> c`. Is it possible to create a generic list with c as the generic parameter?

So something like this:

```
Class<?> c = doSomething();
List<c> list = new ArrayList<c>();
```

Comment: If you could do this, it wouldn't be useful. Generic types are only useful before compiling. If you could do this, you couldn't do anything with it you couldn't do with `List<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

No that is impossible - at least your grammar will not compile. However, you may try to learn *generics* in Java, and see whether that helps your specific case, as this may be a A-B problem.

For example, this works:

```
    <T> int yourFunction(List<T> items) {
        T item = items.get(0);
        // play with the item of type T, yeah!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Class<? extend T> clazz`, `List<T>` can be used for any instance created by `clazz`. For `Class<? super T> clazz`, `List<T>` should only contain instance that are compatibly with `clazz`.

For `Class<?>`, `List<Object>` is probably what you want. Any use of reflection, including `Class` is usually a mistake.